# clarification about theorem $3.10 $ of Brezis functional analysis book.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm referring to the theorem at page $61$. It shows that for a linear operator $T $ between $E $ and $ F$ Banach space are equivalent
(notation: $S$ means strong topology, the norm ome, $W $ weak topology)

$T$ is continuous from $ E, S $ to $F, S$

$T$ is continuous from $E, W$ to $F, W$

$T$ is continuous from $E, S$ to $F, W$

Where by $E, S$ i mean $E$ equipped with the strong topology.
My question is why the same argument is not valid for $T$ between $E, W $ to $F, S$?
I don't know what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $E = F$ and $T = \operatorname{id}$. It's continuous for the other combinations of topologies, but not for $(E,W) \to (F,S)$.

That shows that $(E,W) \to (F,S)$ continuity is a stronger condition than the others.

Since a weak neighbourhood of $0$ contains a neighbourhood of the form

$$\{ e : \lvert \lambda_i(e)\rvert < 1, \; 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n\}$$

for finitely many $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n \in E'$, it contains

$$K := \bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker \lambda_i,$$

a subspace of finite codimension. The image of $K$ under $T$ is a subspace that is contained in a ball of finite radius, hence $K \subset \ker T$, and therefore, the range of $T$ is finite-dimensional. That is a *very* restrictive condition.

Comment: ok i'll work out the details. Thanks, but why the argument of the other proofs in the theorem doesn't work here?

Comment: Another doubt :) why infinite dimensional kernel entail finite dimensional range in your reasoning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Infinite-dimensional kernel does not automatically imply finite-dimensional range. But since every weak neighbourhood contains the intersection of finitely many $\lambda^{-1}(\mathbb{D})$, the subspace is finite-codimensional. As to what exactly doesn't work for $(E,W) \to (F,S)$, it would help if I knew how Brezis proves the other cases. I'm trying to figure out the breakage in the proof I know, though.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{D} $?

Comment: The open unit disk of $\mathbb{C}$; in case of real scalars, the interval $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks again. Brezis didn't explicity prove the fact, he says it is obvious given the proof of T continuous between $ E, S $ and $ F, S \Leftrightarrow $ T continuous between $ E, W $ and $ F, W $.

Comment: I would use the fact that the graph of T continuous between $ E, S $ to $ F, W $ is closed according to the product topology $ S \times W $. But this is coarser than $ S \times S $ so the graph is still closed in this topology then i conclude by the closed graph theorem

Comment: That $(E,S) \to (F,S)$ continuity or $(E,W) \to (F,W)$ continuity implies $(E,S)\to (F,W)$ continuity is obvious, since making the topology on the codomain weaker or on the domain stronger makes it only easier to be continuous. That $(E,S)\to(F,W)$ continuity implies $(E,S) \to (F,S)$ continuity, you can for Banach (or Frechet) spaces with the closed graph theorem (it holds more generally, but that requires a different proof) - neat idea, by the way. The closed graph proof obviously can't be used to deduce $(E,W)\to(F,S)$-continuity, since $(E,W)$ doesn't have the properties needed for the CGT

Comment: and besides, you'd make the topology coarser from $S\times S$ to $W\times S$.

Comment: Ok, you can't use CGT because $(E, W) $ is not a banach space right? But why in the other case ($ E, S $ to $ F, W $ ) the idea work fine? $ F, W $ is not banach right?

Comment: Because the one direction of the CGT is very general. The graph of a continuous map (between topological spaces) $f\colon X\to Y$ is closed if $Y$ is Hausdorff. It's the other direction that requires special properties of the spaces to conclude continuity from closedness. Since $(F,W)$ is Hausdorff, the graph of $T$ is closed in $(E,S)\times (F,W)$. Then it's also closed in the finer topology $(E,S)\times (F,S)$, and then you are in a situation where you can invoke the nontrivial part of the CGT.

Comment: Ok and why the SAME argument is not valid fpr the case $(E, W) \times (F, S) $. Assume T is continuous in this case,  $ F, S $ is hausdorff then the graph is closed. And so on in the same way of your last comment. But this isnt true. Why?

Comment: Oh, that direction, $(E,W) \to (F,S)$ continuity implies $(E,S)\to (F,S)$ continuity, is true. You can prove it by observing that a strengthening of the topology on the domain only introduces new continuous functions (if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in the weaker topology, it also is open in the stronger), or, in this configuration, by the CGT. It's the other direction that fails, a $(E,S) \to (F,S)$-continuous map is generally not $(E,W)\to (F,S)$-continuous.

Comment: Ok now all makes sense:) accepted and thanks for the patience